# Asp.Net HTTPWebRequest Returning JSESSIONID Cookie

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

Building ASP.Net app that interacts with a site which uses a JSESSIONID cookie.
The spec I have been given says to return the Cookie with each request.
I extract the cookie out of the header of the login response OK but when I try to use it in the following request I get a 'PlatformNotSupported error' 
Apparently this is due to an 'improvement' in the Security.
I have seen blogs talking about writing a Proxy Server and also creating Classes derived from IHttpModule.
Confused am I.
Is there a straightforward recommended way of coding a HttpWebRequest so that I can transport the Cookie?

Infrequent user of StackOverflow, tried to post comment, failed, so editing post.
Code is:
  string cookie = "JSESSIONID=" + Session["SessionId"].ToString();

```
        if(Request.Cookies["JSESSIONID"]==null)
        {

            //Request.Headers.Add("Cookie",cookie);//PlatformNotSupportedError
            HttpCookie cook = new HttpCookie("JSESSIONID", Session["SessionId"].ToString());
            Request.Cookies.Add(cook);


        } //The prev login response had the cookie in the header not in the cookies collection so I was trying to send back the same way. ASP.net app at this stage. Will be service after get it going. Thx Bob
```

Comment: Bob do you have a sample of your code that you can post? are you trying to do this via a web service by chance..?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
It turns out I should have made a cookies collection and assigned it to my original login request.
The `SessionId` cookie would then have appeared in the collection when it returned.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
  CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  request.CookieContainer = cookies;
  request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
  request.Method = "POST";
  request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
  request.ContentType = "text/xml";
  using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
  {
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  }
```